# How state 1 has a 0.5 chance of terminating on the left, and state 950 has a 0.25 chance of terminating on the right?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, sutton-barto

Sutton-Barto's RL book (page 203)

> Example 9.1: State Aggregation on the 1000-state Random Walk: Consider a
> 1000-state version of the random walk task (Examples 6.2 and 7.1 on pages 125 and
> 144). The states are numbered from 1 to 1000, left to right, and all episodes begin near
> the center, in state 500. State transitions are from the current state to one of the 100
> neighboring states to its left, or to one of the 100 neighboring states to its right, all with
> equal probability. Of course, if the current state is near an edge, then there may be fewer
> than 100 neighbors on that side of it. In this case, all the probability that would have
> gone into those missing neighbors goes into the probability of terminating on that side
> (thus, state 1 has a 0.5 chance of terminating on the left, and state 950 has a 0.25 chance
> of terminating on the right). As usual, termination on the left produces a reward of
> −1, and termination on the right produces a reward of +1. All other transitions have a
> reward of zero. We use this task as a running example throughout this section.

Question:  I did not understand how state 1 has a 0.5 chance of terminating on the left, and state 950 has a 0.25 chance of terminating on the right. Could someone explain this calculation in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State 1 has zero states on the left, and 100 on the right. The normal probability of getting to a state is 1/200; the remainder from 1.0 indicates termination.

So State 1: 100 x 1/200 = 1/2 = **0.5**, which is the probability of reaching *any* of the 100 states on the right. The remaining **0.5** is thus assigned to terminating, as there are no left states that can be reached.

State 950: you have 100 states on the left (so a **0.5** probability of reaching any of them), but only 50 states on the right. So you have 50 x 1/200 = 1/4 = **0.25**, which is the probability of reaching any of the 50 states on the right. This leaves a probability of **0.25** to terminate.